# Sci-fi book series about the development of a lost colony over generations and a war with Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel

When I was younger I remember reading a book series from the 70s or 80’s.

The basic premise was that a colony ship crashed on an alien planet and lost contact with earth. The book series follows with how this crew develops into a civilisation that spans millennia.

The final book book has them reconnect with an advanced civilisation from Earth where they then face off in a large scale war.

The main thing I remember is the theme being the development of civilisation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How many books were in the series?  (Was it a trilogy or something longer?)  Do you remember any of the cover art?  Other than this being a series, the idea fits several possible novels from that era, such as Clarke's [*The Songs of Distant Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Songs_of_Distant_Earth).

Comment: *The Songs of Distant Earth* (1986) doesn't have conflict with Earth, but Hogan's [*Voyage from Yesteryear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_from_Yesteryear) (1982) does, although the timeframe is too short (around a century).  And of course neither is a series.

Comment: Since you acknowledge that *Darkover* is the answer, please accept Klaus' answer by clicking on the checkmark below the voting arrows beside it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question and put the answer in it. Accept the correct answer instead.

Comment: See OP confirmation comment for answer below.

Answer (score 18):

## Marion Zimmer Bradley's *Darkover* series

Marion Zimmer Bradley's [*Darkover* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkover_series) begins chronologically with *Darkover Landfall* (1972), which follows the survivors of a crashed colony ship. Much later, the planet (named Darkover), is discovered by Terrans, and eventually war ensues between the original colonists (some of whom have developed mental powers through breeding with an elusive native species). This culminates in *The World Wreckers* (1971). There are many other [books in the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Darkover_books), written before, between and after these two, with some of the later co-written with other writers,

[image]

Comment: That’s the one!!!!! It has been driving me mad searching the internet trying to remember all the details! Thank you so much! Now that you mention the psychic powers, that was one of the things that I didn’t know if I was misremembering. God bless you and thank you for being a trove of knowledge!

Comment: @Elyon: Since you have accepted this answer as right, please mark it at such (to the left of the answer title) to close the question. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Not a great match, but possibly this is the *Tyranaël* series (5 books) by Elisabeth Vonarburg. The loss of contact between Earth and the colony is not immediate, but at some point Earth (which was in bad shape to begin with) loses the star-drive technology and doesn't reconnect again until late in the series.  A notable thing about this saga is that colony planet Virginia/Tyranaël was previously inhabited by another civilization that had disappeared just prior to the colonists' arrival. This meant that the colonization was at least in part a re-occupation of previously developed cities.  It turns out the earlier inhabitants decamped to a sort of alternate reality version of the same planet specifically to avoid potential conflict.  The series follows both the fate of the colonists and the fate of the original civilization, leading to their eventual convergence and re-contact with Earth.

Points against the match:  published in the 90s, and I think only the first couple of volumes were translated into English.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One of the other commenters found it, it was the Darkover series. However, after reading this it seems like a book series I’ll soon be picking up as well.

Answer (score 1):

A video game called [Reunion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reunion_(video_game)) has a very similar premise as well:

A colony ship from Earth departs to find new worlds, but soon after it departs a rebellion on Earth itself destroys the government and all contact to Earth is lost. Your colony ship is considered the only surviving bit from the old-style Earthen civilization.

Generations (approx 500 years) later the colony ship settles on an alien planet and starts to reach out to nearby worlds finding both friendly and hostile alien civilizations slowly expanding to more and more solar systems. Meanwhile you also need to advance your own civilization as well.

Nearing the end of the game you find our own Solar System including Earth itself and realize that

> the rebellion was instigated by mind-controlling aliens from a nearby civilization who have taken over Earth

There is a big war at the end of the game where you are trying to re-take control of Earth, and once that's done you are considered victorious.

The game itself is heavily scripted, especially the main plot-points, with a fairly high difficulty - if you miss any of the plot points in time it's usually a quick game over from there.

More information on the game and some screenshots are also available on [MobyGames](https://www.mobygames.com/game/reunion)